# Is there a way to optimize casting jsonb value as double precision in Posgresql by indexing it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have Postgresql table with > 1M records, and there is jsonb column. My application makes a lot of selects like this:

```
select from table_name where (cast(json ->> 'value' as double precision) >= 1;
```

This query takes almost 1500 ms to execute. I can't change the query itself, so i need to build an index for this operation.

I tried to build btree index:

```
create index concurrently ix_json_value_as_number on table_name using btree(cast(json ->> 'value' as double precision));
```

but it didnt give me any query time improvements. Any ideas?

P.S. I use Postgres 9.4.

P.S.S Request explain:

```
Aggregate  (cost=176328.20..176328.20 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1358.130..1358.130 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_name  (cost=3055.46..175455.10 rows=349240 width=0) (actual time=168.344..1285.381 rows=966650 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (((bar->> 'foo'::text))::double precision >= 2.39999999999999991::double precision)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 36082
        Heap Blocks: exact=58417 lossy=105558
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_json_value_as_number (cost=0.00..2968.15 rows=349240 width=0) (actual time=152.711..152.711 rows=966711 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((bar ->> 'foo'::text))::double precision >= 2.39999999999999991::double precision)
Planning time: 0.095 ms
Execution time: 1358.813 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done